# Merging pandas dataframes based on two colums

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge two dataframes based on date and ticker (identifier) and add the values in df2 to df1 based on this. (df1 date is calendardate) This would need to allow duplicates as there are multiple `df1` values for instances in `df2`.

How do I align the returns `df2` with the metrics in `df1`? I get a "check for duplicates" error when I try this:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_index=True,left_on='calandardate',right_on='date')
```

df1

```
 ticker dimension calendardate    datekey reportperiod lastupdated  

None                                                                     
0      ZYXI       ARQ   2018-12-31 2019-02-26   2018-12-31  2019-02-26   
1      ZYXI       ARQ   2018-09-30 2018-11-06   2018-09-30  2019-02-26   
2      ZYNE       ARQ   2018-12-31 2019-03-11   2018-12-31  2019-03-11   
3      ZYNE       ARQ   2018-09-30 2018-11-08   2018-09-30  2019-03-11   
4      ZYME       ARQ   2018-12-31 2019-03-06   2018-12-31  2019-03-06
```

df2

```
date    2018-05-31  2018-06-29  2018-07-31  2018-08-31  2018-09-28  \
ticker                                                               
A              0.0   -0.001292    0.067917    0.022714    0.044418   
AA             0.0   -0.024756   -0.077005    0.032355   -0.095590   
AAC            0.0   -0.129182    0.108858   -0.147257   -0.138826   
AAGIY          0.0   -0.043419    0.003711   -0.019909    0.033082   
AAL            0.0   -0.128158    0.041623    0.023773    0.020998
```

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using samples of your dataframe and expected output, not images

Comment: I have tried df_merged = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_index=True,left_on='calandardate',right_on='date' )

Comment: Not as a comment @Myles.. Properly formatted in the body of the question. I'm saying this so that you're problem can be reproduced more easily. Otherwise you will probably get no answers

Comment: how do I add the dataframe from the juypter notebook, how does the mark up for that work here?

Comment: So simply print your dataframe, make sure there are 4 spaces at the beginning of each line of code (select all + TAB), and paste it here

Comment: I have done it for you Myles :)

Comment: cool thanks - first time - you might have guessed

Comment: No problem. Make sure you put your dataframes into code brackets. Google if unsure. It makes it easier to read. I have done this for you.